# Parametric polymorphism struggles

Tags: java, generics, parametric-polymorphism

In addition to implementing a Bag & List for an assignment, the next step is to create an ordered version.  A requirement is to specify the parametric interface OrderedCollection with the correct type parameters and constraints.  My problem is with implementing it.

An interface `Collection <E>` exists and is defined as

```
public interface Collection<E> extends Iterable<E>{
  public void add(E e);
  public void remove(E e);
  public boolean contains(Object e);
  public void clear();
  public int size();
  public boolean isEmpty();
  public Object[] toArray();
}
```

It is implemented by the classes

```
public class UnorderedList<E> implements Collection<E>
public class UnorderedBag<E> extends UnorderedList<E> implements Collection<E>
```

I have the structures working, and am now trying to implement the sorted version.  To do this and satisfy part of the requirements, I created `OrderedCollection` as

```
public interface OrderedCollection <E extends Comparable<E>> {
  public int compareTo(E e);
}
```

because it is extending the methods already defined in `Collection`, and the only new functionality required is a `compareTo()` method.

However, when I try to implement `OrderedList` by the declaration

```
public class OrderedList<E> extends UnorderedList<E> implements OrderedCollection<E>
```

I get an error stating that

```
Bound mismatch: The type E is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <E
extends Comparable<E>> of the type OrderedCollection<E>
```

As I understand the error message, I need to specify a parameter type that is a valid substitute for the one given in the interface declaration.  However, I've tried

```
OrderedCollection<E extends Comparable<E>>
```

as the implements declarer, but then I get a warning that a syntax error exists on extends.

How do I satisfy the requirements here?

Comment: I'd suggest trying *public class OrderedList<E> extends UnorderedList<E extends Comparable<E>> implements OrderedCollection<E>*. - N.b.: Are you sure about *public int compareTo(E e);* inside your collections? What should that method do?

Comment: Where are requirements? What is a problem? There are no syntax error in string "OrderedCollection<E extends Comparable<E>>".

Comment: @itun, the problem is in the full OrderedList class declaration, E is stated to be a bound error, since it can't substitute for E extends Comparable<E> parameter for the interface.  John Haager's answer helped a great deal and got rid of the errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your declaration of the `OrderedList` class, the generic type of `OrderedList` needs to match the restriction that OrderedCollection expects.

```
public class OrderedList<E extends Comparable<E>> 
             extends UnorderedList<E> 
             implements OrderedCollection<E>
```